# C# Active Directory Search Exception Handling

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to authorise a user's username and password using Active Directory in WinForms, however when a user enters an incorrect username or password, the "DirectoryServicesCOMException was unhandled" error is thrown- what I need is for a Message Box to pop up and inform the user that they have entered an incorrect password, instead of the form breaking. So far what I have is this, but it isn't working - I get the same result i.e. the exception is thrown;

```
 private SearchResult SearchByUsername(DirectorySearcher ds, string username)
        {
            ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "))";
            

            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            ds.ServerTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);

            SearchResult userobject = ds.FindOne();

            if (userobject != null)
            {
                return userobject;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password Entered.");
            }
        }
```

The code seems to error on the SearchResult. Below is a screenshot of the error;
[image]

I'd be more than grateful if someone could advise how to put a messagebox in place to inform the user of an incorrect username/password instead of the form breaking due to the exception.

EDIT: following a reply, I have tried to use a catch block - it is working BUT when a user enters an incorrect username/password, the search results to not research i.e. if the user re-enters the correct username/password after initially having input a wrong one, they still get the MessageBox. They have to close the form and re-open it;

```
 private SearchResult SearchByUsername(DirectorySearcher ds, string username)
        {
            ds.Filter = "(&((&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=User)))(samaccountname=" + username + "))";

            try
            {
                ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                ds.ServerTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                

                SearchResult userobject = ds.FindOne();

                if (userobject != null)

                    return userobject;
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password Provided. Please check credentials entered. ", "Error Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                e.Message.ToString();
                
            }
                return null;
                
               
            
        }
```

Looks like I am nearly there, but just need to know how to 'refresh' or 'clear' the search result if the credentials entered are incorrect to allow the user to re-enter the correct details without having to close and open the form again

Many Thanks,

Comment: [try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

Comment: @SalahAkbari thank you for the very quick reply. I have tried utilising a Catch block, however nothing happens when the login button is clicked, both with a correct password and an incorrect one. Please see the edited question for the updated code I have tried using.

Comment: @SalahAkbari I have corrected the Catch block and it is now working, but only to a certain point. If a user enters a wrong username/password, they indeed get the messagebox warning, and if they correct the username/password the search results do not refresh - they still 'remember' the previous incorrect details. Is there a way to dispose or clear the search results if the credentials provided are wrong to allow the user to try again?

Comment: Make sure you're calling `ds.Dispose()` somewhere.  Whether it solves the problem or not, it's something that should be done after you are done using the object.